# BIML Teradata Source gives query error

Tags: ssis, teradata, biml

I have a biml script designed to transfer data from a Teradata source to a file. We have standard SSIS, so can't use the Attunity driver. I am using an ADO.Net connection, which works correctly if I generate a package with just the connection, and then add a dataflow manually. However, when trying to add the dataflow using BIML, the AdoNetSource gives the following error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server).

I can connect to the Teradata server from my pc no problem and run all the queries.

A simplified version of the biml:

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">  
<Connections>  
    <AdoNetConnection Name="SOURCE_SERVER" Provider="Teradata.Client.Provider.TdConnection, Teradata.Client.Provider, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=76b417ee2e04956c" ConnectionString="Data Source=ourServer;User ID=ourUID;password=ourPWD;" />  
</Connections>  
<Packages>  
    <Package Name="TestPackage">  
        <Connections>    
            <Connection ConnectionName="SOURCE_SERVER" RetainSameConnection="false"/>  
        </Connections>  
        <Tasks>  
            <Dataflow Name="testdf">  
                <Transformations>  
                    <AdoNetSource Name="adosource" ConnectionName="SOURCE_SERVER">  
                        <DirectInput>SELECT 1</DirectInput>    
                    </AdoNetSource>  
                </Transformations>  
            </Dataflow>  
        </Tasks>  
    </Package>  
</Packages></Biml>
```

Comment: I'm confused, you have Teradata as your provider, but your error message is for SQL Server.

Comment: Yes, I guess that is a shortcoming of how the Varigence compiler dll works. The provider and connection string are correct for Teradata, because the compile works without the AdoNetSource, with a connection correctly pointing to Teradata. The compile also works correctly with a SQL AdoNet Connection, and with a Teradata OleDb connection (which is 32 bit only).